# Derivation of a Higher Order Compact Alternating Direction Implicit Method

Tags: pde, finite-difference, operator-splitting

I dont understand how this Higher Order Compact ADI scheme, which is fourth order in time and space, for the wave equation is derived:
I go through the following

Using Tylor's expansion $u(t+h,x,y)$ and $u(t-h,x,y)$ about the point (t,x,y) we have:\
(1)
\begin{equation}
\label{311}
u(t+k,x,y)-2u(t,x,y)+u(t-k,x,y)=k^2\left(\frac{\partial^2 u(t,x,y)}{\partial t^2}\right)+\frac{k^4}{12}\left(\frac{\partial^4 u(t,x,y)}{\partial t^4}\right)+\cdots
\end{equation} 
If $u$ is a solution of $u_{tt}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ then we have the following:\
(2)
\begin{equation}
\label{312}
\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}
\end{equation}
 And \
 (3)
\begin{equation}
\label{313}
\frac{\partial^4 }{\partial t^4}=\frac{\partial^4 }{\partial x^4}+\frac{\partial^4 }{\partial y^4}
\end{equation} (3)
Substituting equations (2) and (3)  in to equation (1) and $u(t+k,x,y)=u^{n+1}_{i,j}$,$u(t-k,x,y)=u^{n-1}_{i,j}$ and $u(t,x,y)=u^{n}_{i,j}$ shows:\
(4)
\begin{equation}
\label{314}
u^{n+1}_{i,j}-2u^{n}_{i,j}+u^{n-1}_{i,j}=k^2\left(\frac{\partial^2u(t,x,y) }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u(t,x,y)}{\partial y^2}\right)+\frac{k^4}{12}\left(\frac{\partial^4 u(t,x,y)}{\partial x^4}+\frac{\partial^4 u(t,x,y)}{\partial y^4}\right)+\cdots
\end{equation} 
Again using Taylor's expansion up to the fourth order difference for the following:\
(5)
\begin{equation}
\label{315}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{h^2}\left(\delta^2_x-\frac{1}{12}\delta_x^4\right)u
\end{equation} 
And \
 (6)
\begin{equation}
\label{316}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=\frac{1}{h^2}\left(\delta^2_y-\frac{1}{12}\delta_y^4\right)u
\end{equation}
And we also have :
\(7)
\begin{equation}
\label{317}
\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)=\frac{1}{h^4}\delta^4_xu
\end{equation} 
And \(8)
\begin{equation}
\label{318}
\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial y^4}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)=\frac{1}{h^4}\delta^4_yu
\end{equation} 
Substituting equations (5)-(8) in to equation (4) shows to the fourth order accuracy:\(9)
\begin{equation}
\label{319}
u^{n+1}_{i,j}-2u^{n}_{i,j}+u^{n-1}_{i,j}=\left(r^2\left( 1+\frac{r^2-1}{12}\delta_x^2\right)\delta^2_x +r^2\left( 1+\frac{r^2-1}{12}\delta_y^2\right)\delta^2_y\right) u_{i,j}^n
\end{equation}
The next step may be applying some operator,but I dont know how to apply and to reach the following ?

$$(1+\frac{1-r^2}{12}\delta_x^2)u^*_{ij}=[2+\frac{1+5r^2}{6}\delta_x^2-\frac{2(1+r^2)}{1-r^2}\delta_y^2]u_{ij}^n-[1+\frac{1-r^2}{12}\delta_x^2]u_{ij}^{n-1}$$
$$(1+\frac{1-r^2}{12}\delta_y^2)u^{n+1}_{ij}=u^*_{ij}+\frac{1-r^2}{12}\delta_y^2[\frac{2(1+10r^2+r^4)}{(1-r^2)^2}u_{ij}^n-u_{ij}^{n-1}]$$

where $h_x=h_y=h$

Comment: Hi Yahya, and welcome to scicomp!  Could you provide a reference to the paper/book where you found this ADI scheme?  Also, please define what $r$ is.

Comment: Dear Paul Thank you for the comment the paper i found is [An efficient fourth order low dispersive finite difference schemes for a 2-D acoustic wave equation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042713004548) by  Sambit Das ,Wenyuan Liao and Anirudh Gupta.   where $r=\frac{v\tau}{h}$

Comment: What have you understood from the paper's derivation thus far?  What aspects of the derivation do you not understand?

Comment: I started from central difference 4 th order approximation to second derivative but i couldnt reach this formula.What i understand from this is that U* is the intermediate time step for ADI

Comment: We can help you much more easily if you can show the work that you tried thus far and where you get stuck.  Please update your question with this information.

Comment: @Paul Dear Paul I updated the question I hope you will help me